# Why won't it remove my items from my Backpack

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm going to cut to the chase. Whenever this script executes:

```
local hotkey = Enum.KeyCode.P

local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local char = plr.Character
local backpackItems = plr.Backpack:GetChildren()

local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local open = false


UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(key, gp)
    if key.KeyCode == hotkey then
        char.UpperTorso.CFrame = CFrame.new(132.109, -84.7, 22.002)
        local takenItemsStorageFolder = Instance.new("Folder")
        
        takenItemsStorageFolder.Parent = game.ReplicatedStorage
        takenItemsStorageFolder.Name = "Removed Items From ".. plr.Name
        backpackItems.Parent = takenItemsStorageFolder
    end 
end)
```

It will teleport your player to a certain location on a map, but the lines involving variables "**backpackItems**", and "**takenItemsStorageFolder**" are trying to remove the tools/items in the player's Backpack. But the script won't complete this on execution.

**Some other information:**

This script is inside of a **TextLabel** in a **ScreenGui**.
(More info if requested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems here:

1. You are creating a table with the backpack items when the script is first executed. Later when the "P" button is pressed you then want to move those objects to the takenItemsStorageFolder. But at that point there might be different items in the Backpack folder.
2. You are trying to parent the backpackItems table to the takenItemsStorageFolder object, but that does not work with a table. Instead you have to iterate through the actual objects (children of the Backpack) and parent each one.

So as a solution instead of

```
backpackItems.Parent = takenItemsStorageFolder
```

I would suggest you do:

```
for i,v in pairs(plr.Backpack:GetChildren()) do
    v.Parent = takenItemsStorageFolder
end
```